# Elixir compiler warning on ignored function return values

Tags: elixir, static-analysis

Is there a way to get a warning—either from the `elixirc` compiler, Credo, or some other linting tool—when I unintentionally ignore the return value of a function?

That is, I'd like a warning in this sample where it ignores the result of `increment_state()`:

```
defmodule CountingServer do
  use GenServer

  def init(_) do
    :timer.send_interval(1000, :tick)
    {:ok, 1}
  end

  def handle_info(:tick, count_state) do
    IO.puts count_state
    increment_state(count_state)
    {:noreply, count_state}
  end

  def increment_state(prev_count) do
    prev_count + 1
  end
end
```

In the above example, we "intended" to return the *incremented* state from the `handle_info/2` call, rather than the "old" state; that is, we intended for the server to print 1, 2, 3, ... instead of printing 1 repeatedly.

If the sample code had *intentionally* ignored the result of the `increment_state/1` call (assigning it to `_`, for instance), no warning would have been necessary.

I've looked through the Credo configuration options and couldn't find anything that seems to fit the bill...

Comment: I think it's hard because there are so many functions used only for their side effects. For example, you do nothing with the return values of `IO.puts/1` or `:timer.send_interval/2`.

Comment: @BrettBeatty, Hm, right... I guess there's no equivalent to C's `void` return type for side effect-only functions. In this case, I'd happily accept the limitation of having to assign the result of my (relatively rare) uses of such functions to `_` in exchange for ruling out this class of bugs. (My bug in production was calling a "mostly side effect" function that sent a network request, then failing to save the GenServer state change that would track that I'd done so.)

Comment: I've never written a credo check before, but it might not be that hard to just check that every expression except the last in a function block is an assignment

Comment: I doubt I follow what would prevent you from typing `_ = increment_state()` when you’ll get accustomed to doing that for all `IO.puts/1` etc?

Comment: Actually I thing that its a bit dangerous to use `_ = increment_state()` in the initial phases of the code. Its much better to always do `state = increment_state()` and credo will complain about that if its not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and made [a Credo check](https://gist.github.com/s3cur3/0f2f1ea61b2528a60ebb2957bc945546) based off Credo's default [UnusedOperation](https://github.com/rrrene/credo/blob/master/lib/credo/check/warning/unused_operation.ex) and [UnusedFunctionReturnHelper](https://github.com/rrrene/credo/blob/master/lib/credo/check/warning/unused_function_return_helper.ex).

Those checks *almost* support what I want to do as-is, but they require essentially a "blacklist" to say exactly which functions' return values must not be ignored; I just had to invert the logic to support warning on any function not present in a whitelist (`Logger.info`, `Enum.each`, etc.).

The check supports adding additional (presumably project-specific) functions to the whitelist via the `.credo.exs` config.

See [the first comment](https://gist.github.com/s3cur3/0f2f1ea61b2528a60ebb2957bc945546#gistcomment-3141748) for instructions on using it in your own project. (TL;DR: Drop the file in your project, add it to both the `requires` and `checks` lists in your `.credo.exs`.)